# Ctrl+C not fully stopping local Web Server in Symfony project

Tags: symfony, xampp, symfony-cli

I'm using PhpStorm with XAMPP. To start my project I use `symfony server:start`, which works fine. However when I want to stop the webserver I used to simply press <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> while in the terminal. However now when I do `symfony server:start` after having used <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> it says

> [WARNING] The local web server is already running.

This has never been the case for me before. Now I have to do `symfony server:stop` to restart the web-server, which messing with my work-flow.

I've tried uninstalling all of XAMPP, PhpStorm, Composer and symfony-cli and then installing it again, but the issue seemed to remain.

The Web server is using PHP CGI 8.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, the Symfony web server or only some process of it is still running.

You can check for running processes using php on Windows like this: `tasklist | findstr php`.

You can also try to just restart the XAMPP server.

But what is such a problem of doing `symfony server:stop` anyways, if it is the proper way to stop the server? I'd suggest just doing that, as it ensures that the server is stopped properly.

In your terminal you can just write it once and then press up arrow to go to the latest commands.